# Using Virtual Paths in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a layout page which is shared across all of the views in my app. That view references the .css in my app. For the sake of reference, I currently have the following at the top of my _layout.cshtml file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/themes/default/app.css" />
```

I am planning on taking this app and loading into a phone app via PhoneGap. Because of that, I cannot use /css/themes/default.app.css. Instead, I need to get it converted to a string that is relative to the path of the file. For instance, I need to dynamically generate a value that looks something like the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../css/themes/default/app.css" />
```

The number of "../" will be determined based on how deep it is. I figured there would be a utility or something built into the ASP.NET MVC 3 framework to do this. However, I can't find anything. I have a LOT of files and I don't want to have to manually update all of the url patterns. Is there a utility that will automatically handle what I'm trying to acomplish? If so, how?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [UrlHelper.Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action.aspx) HTML Helper method .

> This method Converts a virtual (relative) path to an application absolute path.

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/css/themes/default/app.css")" 
                                       rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

You may drop your `css` folder under the `Content` directory in the root of your MVC project

Comment: when I use Url.Content, it converts "~/css/themes/default/app.css" to "/css/themes/default/app.css". What I need though is something like "../../css/themes/default/app.css"

Comment: those files are outside your root ?

Comment: I guess I'm not sure. The whole routing thing in MVC regularly confuses me. I will say that I have my css directory in MVC.csproj/resources and my cshtml files are in MVC.csproj/Views

Comment: Use the conventions MVC provides. Keep your css/images inside the Content folder and use the HTML Helper methods

Comment: is there anyway to salvage it if I'm already a long ways down my current path? Or is the only way to restructure my folders?